# Visual Studio - Auto Formatting - protect some code areas from beeing auto formatted in a workgroup

Tags: c#, visual-studio, version-control, autoformat

I am working in a team of developers, code is shared by SVN server/ client structure. I want to protect a code area from being auto formatted. Most of the other engineers are frequently working in this area of the code and some of them use auto format.

I do not want to turn it off permanently by using options of the UI (I know the possible settings already - but I do not want to force the team members to tick all those boxes and therefore do without auto format in all the code).

I am looking for a solution with aditional code like a region property or sth. like that... so just like

"#region" and 
"#endregion"

could look like this:

"#donotautoformat" and 
"#enddonotautoformat"

I did not find any hints (maybe searching wrong) anywhere but I cannot believe that something that simple does not exist in VS...

Comment: this question does not related to svn/group, remove the irrelevant tags. 'VisualStudio' tag would be more appropriate.

Comment: The common way is to have rules for all developers. One rule is about formatting and all have to use the same formatting guidelines. You can export/import that settings from/to VS including autoformat on save.

Comment: Another option would be http://haacked.com/archive/2011/05/22/an-obsessive-compulsive-guide-to-source-code-formatting.aspx/

Comment: kennyzx - I know, but I was not allowed to add the Tag VisualStudio (need reputation 1500 for that ^^ ). "SVN" was proposed, so I simply used this to be able to pose the question at all. I also was required to add 5 tags. Perhaps some admins should reconsider the requirements...

Comment: Sir Rufo - thx for your second comment. I will check this. But I think you did not get the basic idea. It is not about formatting the whole code. It is more like setting an "excetption tag" in the code to keep VS from applying any automatic formatting rule (no matter which). This is only one cs file, I do not like to be reformatted. I just could not believe, that it is not possible to add a region which tells VS "do not format this" - no matter who opens the code...